# WP set auth cookie using Ajax is not saved to browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, authentication, plugin-json-api

We are creating an external dashboard that uses Wordpress data, obviously, we use [WP REST API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org/)

We want total separation from the traditional WP Dashboard, but we also want to log in user "behind the scenes" to WP Admin Dashboard, so **we can redirect user to some plugin admin UI pages; due to limitation of the WP REST API**

This is what we did, we created a custom plugin that has the function createAuthkey below that does Logins in user then creates a key (token).

The important part we care about is if the login succeeds (wp_authenticate()), we want also to save the wp_auth_cookie on the browser, so **even if the user is not directly logged into /wp-admin, if now the browser enters WP admin pages, we want them to be logged in** and therefore we use wp_set_auth_cookie(), but the AJAX response **DOES NOT save the returned cookie in the browser resources (but correctly returns it in response)** and therefore when the user is redirected to WP admin page, they are logged out

```
function createAuthKey( WP_REST_Request $request )
{
    // Get login information
    $username   = $request->get_param( 'username' );
    $password   = $request->get_param( 'password' );

    $user = wp_authenticate( $username, $password );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
     return false;
    }

    $converter = new Encryption;
    $encoded = $converter->encode($username . ":" . $password);

    // Set Cookie: NOT SAVED TO BROWSER!!!
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);

    return ['key' => $encoded, 'cookie' => $_COOKIE];
}
```

Comment: How are you running the function `createAuthKey()`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your custom dashboard is on a different domain/subdomain than the WordPress installation. Cookies can only be set for the current domain.

Typically cookies will not work cross domain. So your dashboard cannot create a cookie for the WordPress website. Theoretically it's possible to bypass with some server configurations, but this technique has to be supported by the users browser.